# Javascript google heatmap gradient settings for multiple layers

Tags: javascript, heatmap

Using google maps javascript api, I want to create two heatmap overlays with different color gradients for each overlay. So far I have been able to create the two overlays, but when I try to apply a different gradient to each one there is no output.

Here is the code:

```
  var map, heatmap, heatmap2;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 11,
        center: {lat: 47.608013, lng: -122.335167},
        mapTypeId:'hybrid'
    });
    heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        data: getPoints(),
        map: map
        gradient: getGrad()
    });
    heatmap2 = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
        data:   getPoints1(),
        map:    map
        gradient: getGrad1()
    });
  }
function getGrad () {
return [
    rgba(255,0,0,0),
        // more values here
];
}   
function getGrad1 ()    {
return [
    rgba(0,255,255,0),
        //more values here
];
}
```

To clarify, whenever the gradient properties get commented out everything works with the default gradient. The code above produces no output. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The gradient values are supposed to be strings. `rgba` is a css function, not a js one and so in the developer console you should be seeing several errors stating that the function is not defined.

```
function getGrad1 ()    {
    return [
        'rgba(0,255,255,0)',
            //more values here
    ];
}
```

Have a look at the example here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the css. However, I tried that and it's still not displaying.  Side note: sorry if this is off topic. I'm editing this in Notepad++, is there a better editor that will debug?

Comment: @vervair Notepad++ is fine. Any code editor would be. However, with javascript, they don't do the debugging. You would want to go into your browser and use the developer console (press F12). That will show any/all errors you are getting. Fix those and it will work.

Comment: I forgot to place a comma after my map property, fixing that got it to work. Thanks for the debugging advice @Jonathan Kuhn. I've mostly only worked in VBA, so this is a new experience.